# Create an array with device logical name based on list of serial numbers

Tags: arrays, bash, list, scsi

I'm tying to identify disks based on a list of UUID I get out of an api call.

The list of devices on the linux VM is following:

```
NAME="sda" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_5_0_70509_a07b6add_60c9_4758_8b27_0afe77820dbd"
NAME="sdb" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_625_ae748138_9bc0_4499_8068_d00a84a800b6"
NAME="sdc" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_626_8a082956_a2be_42ca_a14b_7d21ed3d5a2d"
NAME="sdd" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_627_6185353f_5c13_47ab_af58_b72d4d07106b"
NAME="sde" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_628_fbeed366_6956_4de1_a217_487d75fd003c"
NAME="sdf" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_629_019dcefb_0e1b_4086_96a9_982ae52fd88a"
NAME="sdg" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_630_5d0b55e8_d0bd_4ee4_a2be_0bef88d94732"
NAME="sdh" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_631_823beaed_1c2e_4203_ab5f_be294382d0c5"
NAME="sdi" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_632_e4ee8620_5b53_4187_8f8c_7123ee8d3486"
NAME="sdj" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_633_41551a1b_7dd9_4fd4_95bc_1fcdebb9dc85"
NAME="sdk" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_634_12d517fc_e726_4512_b176_5d4075d0ecfe"
NAME="sdl" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_635_d682eee4_cec0_4809_9efe_97aec7bf15d0"
NAME="sdm" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_636_59ea679e_cbd3_4cf5_a974_67409b719391"
NAME="sdn" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_637_5523c88e_310a_4fb6_b76f_48f624d1ce1f"
NAME="sdo" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_638_0e189f7a_785d_46f1_bb56_8f422d421ecb"
NAME="sdp" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_639_9143ba87_d742_4130_bbe0_2084e8ebad3f"
NAME="sdq" SERIAL="NUTANIX_NFS_18_0_640_3b823817_c2b6_49af_9a55_fc4706216501"
```

The list of drives I want to identify is in this format:

```
'ae748138_9bc0_4499_8068_d00a84a800b6'
'8a082956_a2be_42ca_a14b_7d21ed3d5a2d'
'6185353f_5c13_47ab_af58_b72d4d07106b'
'fbeed366_6956_4de1_a217_487d75fd003c'
'019dcefb_0e1b_4086_96a9_982ae52fd88a'
'5d0b55e8_d0bd_4ee4_a2be_0bef88d94732'
'823beaed_1c2e_4203_ab5f_be294382d0c5'
'e4ee8620_5b53_4187_8f8c_7123ee8d3486'
'41551a1b_7dd9_4fd4_95bc_1fcdebb9dc85'
'12d517fc_e726_4512_b176_5d4075d0ecfe'
'd682eee4_cec0_4809_9efe_97aec7bf15d0'
'59ea679e_cbd3_4cf5_a974_67409b719391'
'5523c88e_310a_4fb6_b76f_48f624d1ce1f'
'0e189f7a_785d_46f1_bb56_8f422d421ecb'
'9143ba87_d742_4130_bbe0_2084e8ebad3f'
'3b823817_c2b6_49af_9a55_fc4706216501'
```

I need to identify the logical name for only the UUIDs on that list in order to create a LVM volume group out of them. But I'm don't understand how to proceed from there. Anyone can propose an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `'`s from you list of UUIDs (can be done with `tr`) you could use simply `grep` to extract the corresponding lines from your list of devices. To extract only the values of `NAME="..."` from these lines use `cut`.

```
grep -Ff <(tr -d \' < fileListOfUUIDs) fileListOfDevices | cut -d\" -f2
```

If the inputs you showed us are not stored in files but generated by commands you can use

```
commandListOfDevices | grep -Ff <(commandListOfUUIDs | tr -d \') | cut -d\" -f2
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine. 

`lsblk -nodeps -no name,serial -PS /dev/sd* | grep -Ff <(cat vmdisks_uuid.txt | tr -d \') | cut -d\" -f2`

Unfortutenaly, I can't vote... Not enough reputation yet here

Comment: Glad I could help. No problem that you cannot vote yet. However, since this solved your problem I would be happy if you could accept this answer. Accepting an answer also closes the question. Click on the checkmark below this answer's score on the top left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ***extract field values from match results generated by a set of tokens***. `sed` or `awk` can do the trick.

To extract the value of a field called `NAME` from one of the match results simply do this:

```
josh@linux ~ $ result='NAME="sda" FSTYPE="ext4" SERIAL="NUTANIX_...dbd"'
josh@linux ~ $ echo $result | sed -e 's/.*NAME="//; s/".*//;'
sda
```

To extract the value of a field called `FSTYPE` from the same match result:

```
josh@linux ~ $ echo $result | sed -e 's/.*FSTYPE="//; s/".*//;'
ext4
```

What if the order of the field changes? ..well the same code works.

```
josh@linux ~ $ result='FSTYPE="ext4" NAME="sda" SERIAL="NUTANIX_...dbd"'
josh@linux ~ $ echo $result | sed -e 's/.*NAME="//; s/".*//;'
sda
```

With this in mind, extraction of field values from all match results can then be processed in a loop. I have created a small script to automate the process and I am posting it here in the hope that it would be useful.

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# usage: doodle -F <file-containing-pattern(s)>
#        doodle -P <pattern(s)>
#

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo 'invalid argument...'; exit;
else
pattern=
fi

if [ "$1" == "-F" ]; then
if [ ! -r $2 ]; then
echo "unable to read - $2"; exit
else
pattern=$(cat $2)
fi
elif [ "$1" == "-P" ]; then
pattern=$2
else
echo 'invalid argument...'; exit;
fi

if [ -z "$pattern" ]; then
echo 'invalid argument...'; exit;
fi

declare -a buffer
readarray buffer

if [ ${#buffer[*]} -gt 0 ]; then
for token in $pattern; do
for i in ${!buffer[*]}; do
match=$(echo ${buffer[i]} | sed -n "/$token/=");
if [ -n "$match" ]; then
##### Option 1 ##############################################################
# Uncomment the next line to print the same result that 'grep' would print.
#echo -e $(echo ${buffer[i]} | sed "s/$token/\\\\e[91m$token\\\\e[0m/");

##### Option 2 ##############################################################
# Uncomment the next line to print characters before the first [:space:]
#echo ${buffer[i]} | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }';

##### Option 3 ##############################################################
# Uncomment the next line to email device-id to NSA
#TODO...

##### Option 4 ##############################################################
# Uncomment the next line to extract value of 'NAME' field
echo ${buffer[i]} | sed -e 's/.*NAME="//; s/".*//;'

##### Additional Option #####################################################
# Uncomment the next line (break command) to process one match per token
break;
fi
done
done
fi

unset buffer
```

To use this script, simply:

1. Copy the text in the above snippet into a file called *doodle*.
2. Open terminal and type:

```
josh@linux ~ $ chmod a+x doodle
```

To process tokens saved in a file called *device-id.txt*:

```
josh@linux ~ $ lsblk -nodeps -no name,serial -PS /dev/sd* | ./doodle -F device-ids.txt
```

To process tokens supplied as a single string:

```
josh@linux ~ $ lsblk -nodeps -no name,serial -PS /dev/sd* | ./doodle -P 'ae748138_9bc0_4499_8068_d00a84a800b6
8a082956_a2be_42ca_a14b_7d21ed3d5a2d
6185353f_5c13_47ab_af58_b72d4d07106b
...
3b823817_c2b6_49af_9a55_fc4706216501'
```

The script is very generic and you an can easily adapt it for use in related problems. You will find lots of tutorials on `bash`, `sed` and `awk` on the internet. There is also a comprehensive bash reference at [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).